# Extract WORD between two constant strings

Tags: bash, awk, sed, grep

I have the following string

```
xml_srx_name="<name>SRX-NAME</name>"
```

I am trying to print the text between > and <
so it would print **SRX-NAME**

I am really close but this is what I get: **>SRX-NAME<** which is what I was able to achieve with this command:

```
$ cat $xml_srx_name | awk '/SRX-NAME/ {print $1}' | grep -oPz "(?s)>.*?<" | tr '\0' '\n'

Output:
>SRX-NAME<
```

Comment: `sed -E 's|.*<name>([^<]+)</name>.*|\1|' <<< "$xml_srx_name"`

Comment: Is it `cat $xml_srx_name` or `echo $xml_srx_name`?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can try

1. Add `| tr -d '<>'` in the end
2. Use `cat … |grep -o SRX-NAME`
3. Use `cat … |cut -d \> -f 2 | cut -d \< -f 1`

Answer (score 2):

If you end up with a compound command that uses `cat`, `awk`, `grep` and `tr` you probably have a nice example of anti-pattern. `awk` alone is enough:

```
$ xml_srx_name="<name>SRX-NAME</name>"
$ awk -F'<|>' '/SRX-NAME/ {print $3}' <<< "$xml_srx_name"
SRX-NAME
```

Or with `sed`:

```
$ sed '/SRX-NAME/s/.*>\(.*\)<.*/\1/' <<< "$xml_srx_name"
SRX-NAME
```

Answer (score 2):

You could also use only `grep -oP` using a perl compatible regex:

```
<(name>)\K[^<]+(?=</\1)
```

Or write out the full pattern:

```
<name>\K[^<]+(?=</name>)
```

**Explanation**

- `<` Match literally
- `(name>)\K` Capture `name>` in group 1
- `[^<]+` Match 1+ chars other than `<`
- `(?=</\1)` Positive lookahead, assert  to the right

Example

```
xml_srx_name="<name>SRX-NAME</name>"
grep -oP "<(name>)\K[^<]+(?=</\1)" <<< "$xml_srx_name"
```

Output

```
SRX-NAME
```

[bash demo](https://tio.run/##S0oszvj/vyI3J764qCI@LzE31VbJBkTZBQdF6Po5@rra6IO5SlzpRakFCrr5AQpKNhpgIc0Y7@g4m1htDXtbG/0YQ00lBRsbGwUlFWTTlP7/BwA)

---

Or using `sed` with a capture group:

```
xml_srx_name="<name>SRX-NAME</name>"

sed 's/.*<name>\([^<]\+\)<\/name>.*/\1/' <<< "$xml_srx_name"
```

[sed demo](https://tio.run/##S0oszvj/vyI3J764qCI@LzE31VbJBkTZBQdF6Po5@rra6IO5SlxcxakpCurF@npaEAUxGtFxNrEx2jGaNjEQNXpa@jGG@uoKNjY2CkoqyIYq/f8PAA)

Answer (score 1):

```
input="test<hello>text"

rightpart=${input#*<}   # remove prefix up to "<" (included)
output=${rightpart%>*}  # remove suffix from ">" (included)

echo $output
```

Or

Using extglob in bash, you can do this in single step:

```
shopt -s extglob
input='test<hello>heythere'
echo "${input//@(*<|>*)/}"
```

Here @(*<|>*) matches a substring from start to < character OR a substring from > to end. Using // we replace all such instances with an empty string.

Comment: Thanks for the quick reply! I got the following output using your command: /name

Comment: Maybe try the extglobal method

Comment: I added another option without extglobal also

Answer (score 0):

You might use GNU `grep` with zero length assertion as follows let `file.txt` content be

```
xml_srx_name="<name>SRX-NAME</name>"
```

then

```
grep -Po "(?<=\>).*(?=\<)" file.txt
```

output

```
SRX-NAME
```

Explanation: find 0 or more any characters after `>` and before `<`.

*(tested in GNU grep 3.4)*

Answer (score 0):

Using any sed or awk in any shell on every Unix box:

```
$ xml_srx_name="<name>SRX-NAME</name>"

$ echo "$xml_srx_name" | awk -F'[<>]' '{print $3}'
SRX-NAME

$ echo "$xml_srx_name" | sed 's/.*>\(.*\)<.*/\1/'
SRX-NAME
```

Any script that includes `SRX-NAME` is pointless as it means you already know the string you're trying to find and so could just do `echo 'SRX-NAME'` instead.